# Google Script - HTML Style

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am working with Google script to send out an HTML file as an email and I'm running into issues with styling for the entire table that is within my sheet.

I've tried multiple combinations of align, text-align, using equal sign and colons, and nothing seems to work.

Ideally I could just write `<style>table,th,tr {align: center}` but it doesn't work.

I've tried doing it in an HTML simulator and the following works yet this doesn't work in the Google script interface:

```
  <style>
    table, th, td {border-collapse: collapse; text-align:center}
  </style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't know enough about CSS to split it up in another file as so ideally I could do it all within an HTML `<style>` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App Script HTML table styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674117/google-app-script-html-table-styling)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I was able to search other people's code and looks like it all needs to be in quotation marks. Also no style brackets for the table.

Answer (score -1):

try add !important in your styles.

```
table, th, tr { align: center !important }
```

Test too the property text-align: center;

Test too:

```
table {
  display: table;
  text-align:center;
}
```

I hope helped you.

Comment: <style>
       table, th, td {border-collapse: collapse !important; text-align:center!important}
      </style> did not work.

Comment: This also didn't work: <style>
       table, th, td {border-collapse: collapse !important; align='center'!important}
      </style>

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in other sections of the code using this: "<tr align= 'center'>" does work. So it's just in the style section that it doesn't like it?

Comment: Also when I use it in the table example <tr align= 'center'> the "align" is in blue, where as when it's done within the style bracket, it's in red?

Comment: This also didn't work: <table style="align:center" >

Comment: table {
  display: table;
  text-align:center;
}